# How to prevent a javascript/backbone.js cloned model from sharing attributes

Tags: javascript, clone, cloning, backbone.js

I'm working with backbone.js models, so I don't know if my question is particular to the way backbone handles cloning or if it applies to javascript in general.  Basically, I need to clone a model which has an attribute property assigned an object.  The problem is that when I update the parent or clone's attribute, the other model is also updated.  Here is a quick example:

```
var A = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var a = new A({'test': {'some': 'crap'}});
var b = a.clone();

a.get('test')['some'] = 'thing';
// I could also use a.set() to set the attribute with the same result

console.log(JSON.stringify(a))
console.log(JSON.stringify(b))
```

which logs the following:

```
{"test":{"some":"thing"}}
{"test":{"some":"thing"}}
```

I would prefer to clone *a* such that *b* won't be referencing any of its attributes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how about a javascript deep-clone, would that work for you? checkout http://keithdevens.com/weblog/archive/2007/Jun/07/javascript.clone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backdone does not do a deep-clone, but only clone first level attributes. You have to clone the values yourself (when it is a hash or array for exemple).

Comment: Yeah, my final solution was to create a new model and pass in a deep clone, using jQuery.  var b = new A($.extend(true, {}, a))

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
var A = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var a = new A({'test': {'some': 'stuff'}});
var b = new A(a.model.toJSON());
```

Adapted from this answer: [How to clone a backbone collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596999/how-to-clone-a-backbone-collection)

Comment: The ````toJSON```` approach is the nicest, imo.

Comment: This doesn't work as the `toJSON` method returns a shallow-copied clone of the attributes hash using the underscore `clone` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
var A = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var a = new A({'test': {'some': 'stuff'}});
var b = a.clone();

b.attributes = $.extend(true, {}, b.attributes);

// try to overwrite "some" without affecting "a" model
var someStuff = {'test': {'some' : 'other stuff'}};
b.set(someStuff);

console.log(a.toJSON());
console.log(b.toJSON());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RLWzm/